# Connecting to a queue without specifying the queue manager name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ibm-mq, mq

I am new to MQ..
I have a requirement.
Can I connect to a particular queue, using java, on a server without specifying the queue manager name?
I have all the details like host name, port number, request, response queue name etc.,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  If the app specifies the QMgr name, then the name specified must actually match the QMgr connected to.   However, if the app leaves the QMgr name blank, then whatever QMgr responds on that host, port and channel is accepted.

For example, if you define a managed object it might look like this:

```
DEFINE  CF(JMSDEMOCF) +
        SYNCPOINTALLGETS(YES) +
        TRAN(client) +
        HOST(127.0.0.1) CHAN(MYAPP.SVRCONN) PORT(1414) +
        QMGR( )
```

If not using JNDI, omit the environment hashtable entry for the QMgr name.